# Static reference to WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to get random CSP nonce hash?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, content-security-policy, nonce

I have a `WebSecurityConfiguration` that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Inside it, I generate the random hash for the CSP nonce.

```
private static final String CSP = "script-src 'self'{nonce}; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/; img-src 'self'; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com/; object-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'; report-uri http://127.0.0.1:8080/report";
public String CSP_NONCE;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        CSP_NONCE = Util.byteArrayToHex(Util.RandomHash()); // Generate a random hash.

        http.headers()
            .contentTypeOptions().and()
            .xssProtection().and()
            .cacheControl().and()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity().and()
            .frameOptions().and()
            .contentSecurityPolicy(CSP.replace("{nonce}", " 'nonce-" + CSP_NONCE + "'"));
    }
```

I would like to access this hash value from one of the controller classes but since the `WebSecurityConfiguration` is not instantinated, I can only make a static reference to it, which does not work.

How can I direct access this class or transfer information between `WebSecurityConfiguration` and and one of the Controllers?

Answer (score 3):

i was able to get this running with this code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements Filter {
    @Override public void destroy() { }
    @Override public void init   (final FilterConfig fc) { }
    @Override public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        request.setAttribute("nonce", nonce);
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self'; default-src 'self'; script-src 'nonce-"+nonce+"'; object-src 'self'; style-src 'nonce-"+nonce+"'");
        if(chain!= null) chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { http.addFilterAfter(this, CsrfFilter.class).headers().frameOptions().deny();  }
}
```

And in the controler class i access it via:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", consumes=ALL) public String index(@RequestAttribute("nonce") final String nonce) throws Exception;
```